# Strange Behavior With DIVs and 100% Height in CSS

Tags: html, css

A seemingly trivial problem.

I have a very basic page in Visual Studio 2010.  It's got a master page...

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

...with...

```
<div class="divStretch" />
```

...alone in the content.

CSS is:

```
body, form, html
{
    background-color: Black;
    height: 100%;
}

body
{
    margin: auto;
}

.divStretch
{
    background-color: Red;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Now with the `<div>` tags around the ContentPlaceHolder, the whole page is black.  That is, the content div doesn't show up.  Without the `<div>` tags, red's everywhere and the height of the content div is about twice as high as the window height, causing a vertical scrollbar to appear.

All I'd like is for the content div to exactly fill the window.

Comment: What browser, and are you using a DOCTYPE?

Comment: IE9 and Chrome 12.  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: Maybe I'm just not understanding how your site's markup is, but I'm not able to replicate the problem you're having. http://jsfiddle.net/jzuNg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I am new here, I am not allowed to add comments to your question - sorry about that! I'll try my best at answering your question and will assume some things. I'll edit the answer if I'm wrong on the assumptions.

I'm assuming that by the "content div" you mention towards the end, you are referring to the div that's inside the form, and when you say you'd like it to exactly fill the window you're referring to the height (if you'd like to fill the width in this example, just add width: 100%)

What I've come up with: http://jsfiddle.net/trev/3xuzZ/

I've used the following CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: black;
}

.contentDiv {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: red;
}
```

And the following HTML:

```
<body>
<form>
    <div class="contentDiv">
        <input type="text" /> <br />
        <input type="text" /> <br />
        <input type="text" /> <br />
        <input type="text" /> <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Button!" />
    </div>
</form> 
</body>
```

This will take over the entire browser window though, covering any other elements you may have on the page and I'm not sure if that's what you wanted.

Comment: JSFIDDLE's a great tool.  And your CSS pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: One niggle.  Because position is fixed, this div floats outside of the parent div in the master page.  If I were to apply margins to the parent div, I'd have to repeat this in contentDiv's CSS to make my website consistent.  Is there a way to achieve this same behavior without fixed position?

Comment: I'm thinking about relative and absolute positioning here. Give me a moment as I mess around with it, I don't know how your site is laid out, but maybe try making the parent div "position: relative" and change the position from 'fixed' to 'absolute'.

EDIT:
Does your site have a scroll bar at all? Or is it meant to it on a single page (grooveshark-like for example).

Comment: @S. Valmont I don't know of a way to do it without fixed positioning, you may need to change how your site is currently laid out. Here is what I have come up with [here - JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/trev/vMmRB/)